# How to replace all occurrences of two substrings with str_replace()?

Tags: php, str-replace, spaces

Currently I have this code which replaces any double space with a `<br />`.

It works as expected:

```
<tr class="' . ($counter++ % 2 ? "odd" : "even") . '">
    <td>Garments:</td>
    <td>' . str_replace('  ', '<br /><br />', trim($result['garment_type'] ) ) . '</td>
</tr>
```

However I want to do another `str_replace()` on the same line to replace any single spaces with a pipe character `|`.

I tried duplicating the code but that just creates another `TD` for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question would be improved if it provided some sample input data (`$result['garment_type']`) and the expected output string.  Remember this page will be visited thousands of times in the future by people seeking education.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the array does matter otherwise you will get `<br|/>` instead of `<br />` so try:

```
str_replace(array(' ','||'), array('|','<br /><br />'), trim($result['garment_type'] ));
```

Something like this:

```
echo str_replace(array(' ','||'), array('|','<br /><br />'), 'crunchy  bugs are so   tasty man');
```

Gives you:

```
crunchy<br /><br />bugs|are|so<br /><br />|tasty|man
```

Basically you are changing each space first to `|` then you are changing any that have two beside each other (`||`) to `<br /><br />`.

If you go the other way, you will change two spaces to `<br /><br />` and then you are changing single spaces to `|` and inbetween the `<br />` there is a space, so you end up with `<br|/>`.

**EDIT with your code:**

```
'<tr class="' . ($counter++ % 2 ? "odd" : "even") . '">
    <td>Garments:</td>
    <td>' . str_replace(array(' ','||'), array('|','<br /><br />'), trim($result['garment_type'] )) . '</td>
</tr>'
```

Comment: This worked except it disappeared all the TR's under this

Comment: That's because I never included those parts. Just replace your string replace with my string replace. Keep your other stuff.

Comment: Would be something like this?    <td>' . str_replace(array(' ','||'), array('|','<br /><br />'), trim($result['garment_type'] )); . '</td>

Comment: Got it. This code works for me.    <td>' . str_replace(array(' ','||'), array('|','<br /><br />'), trim($result['garment_type'] )) . '</td>

Comment: Yup, that's exactly how to implement it!

Comment: Awesome. Quick question and I'm done. How would this work if I want to replace 3 spaces with a | and keep 2 spaces with the BR BR

Comment: You should be able to use these two replacement arrays `array(' ','|||','||'), array('|','|','<br /><br />')`. Try that

Comment: That would eliminate the 1 space with the | ?

Comment: No, it's just the order, it first replaces all single spaces with `|`, then since you want three spaces to be `|`, you replace those first with `|`, then you replace any doubles `||` with `<br /><br />`.

Comment: Got it. What if I want to eliminate the single spaces. And just do replace 3 spaces with | and double spaces with BR BR

Comment: Then you should be able to do `array('   ','  ',' '), array('|','<br /><br />','')`. 3 spaces in the first, 2 spaces in second, 1 space in 3rd on the first array (they are showing as the same). This is also assuming you are removing from the `br`? Although that is still valid html.

Comment: Sorry I think I confused you. Basically I just want to replace 3 spaces with | and 2 spaces with BR BR. Ignore the original 1 space question.

Comment: Just use `array('   ','  '), array('|','<br /><br />')`

Comment: Not sure why the downvote...it always baffles me why downvoters do so without leaving a comment...if perhaps these people could bestow their great wisdom upon the community, it would benefit us all!

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with this one and the explanation is good.  It must be a sour-grapes downvote.  It is correct, so I have no problem with neutralizing it.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass arrays to str_replace

```
$what[0] = '  ';
$what[1] = ' ';

$with[0] = '<br /><br />';
$with[1] = '|';

str_replace($what, $with, trim($result['garment_type'] ) )
```

Comment: How would I use that within my code. An example would be great

Comment: Downvoted this answer because it is incorrect / doesn't provide the desired output. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6109975759520598646ebb4925af32147b02d9e3

Answer (score 1):

To get around the issues with `str_replace` (space in `<br />` being replaced with `|`) try `strtr`:

```
echo strtr(trim($result['garment_type']), array(' '=>'|', '  '=>'<br /><br />'));
```